# How can a File having content size in GBs be read in memory as a string using Java IO?

Tags: java, java-io

I have a file containing a very long continuous string without line breaks. I need to read this file efficiently into memory as a string.

I understand that all of the content cannot be stored into memory in one go without running into OutOfMemoryError. However, I need to read this file, get the content into string and do some processing over this string by converting it into a character array.

I need to understand some efficient ways to achieve this objective.

Comment: If you *need* the whole file in a `char` array, then you *will* run into OOME whenever the file size is bigger than the amount of available memory (possibly earlier, due to how strings are represented in-memory in Java). So if the file size is arbitrarily large, then no, there's no way to cheat here, you'll have to find a way to process the file in chunks.

Comment: What you describe is impossible. You might be able to process it in chunks of smaller strings. But you can not represent the whole file content as single `String`, as it would then run out of memory.

Comment: Here is a term that might help you to convert your _processing algorithm_ to one that actually suits your big data: [Online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm)

Comment: In my entire 20 years of java, I have never seen a file problem which one can NOT be solve without keeping whole file in memory. If you give samples and elaborate why you have to read whole file in memory then we can provide alternatives. Without that, answer is no - you can not do this without running into troubles.

Comment: I feel oddly reminded of [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416957/how-to-read-large-files-a-single-continuous-string-in-java) (which was recently re-posted)

Comment: *"I understand that what I want to do is impossible, but how do I do it?"*

Comment: Flagging this as a duplicate [How to read large files (a single continuous string) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416957/how-to-read-large-files-a-single-continuous-string-in-java)

Comment: @Zabuza thanks a lot. Reading in chunks can be a good alternative.

Comment: @searchengine27 I think yes, this answers my question. I will go through the answer thoroughly and apply the suggestions provided.  Thank you.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yes processing in chunks will be a good alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Try using file streams, in order to partially read the the file and process it.

```
try{
   FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
   byte[] data = new byte[1024];
   while(inputStream.read(data) != -1){
      processData(new String(data));
   }
}catch(IOException e){
   e.printstacktrace();
}
```

Comment: 1. This reads arbitrarily large chunks and tries to convert them to `String`. This will fail when the data is in an encoding that uses more than 1 byte per character (even if just sometimes). 2. Even if you don't run into this, processing arbitrary-size chunks can be hard. 3. This uses the platform default encoding instead of specifying one explicitly, that is almost always an error. 4. If you wanted to read text, the wrap your `InputStream` in an `InputStreamReader` instead, as that is the intended way to do that and *also* fixes problem #1 as a side-effect.

Comment: While this is certainly a good suggestions in general, it does not solve the question OP is asking. At least not in the current specific way OP phrased it. Actually, OPs question is, right now, probably unsolvable. So any answer will likely not meet the criteria defined in [answer].